# Unknown devices in Device Manager after migrating a VM to Azure

Tags: azure

I recently migrated a Windows 2008 R2 VM that was running in Hyper-V on a Windows 2008 R2 host to Azure. Upon starting it up in the Azure virtual machine, Windows is showing three Unknown Devices in device manager.  The first has a value of ACPI\Hyper_V_Gen_Counter_V1 in the Hardware ID.  The other two simply show VMBUS(unique ID) in the Hardware ID value.

I'm wondering if these are the remnants of the Hyper-V Integration Services that were installed when the VM was running on Hyper-V locally?  And, if so, should they still be installed when the VM is running in Azure? Are there other integration components that should be installed for VM's running in Azure?

Comment: Have same problem with fresh install from Windows 2008 CD on Windows 10 Hyper-V host. 8 Other devices - "ACPI\Hyper_V_Gen_Counter_V1" and 7 with various VMBUS\{GUID} HardwareIDs

Answer (score 0):

The VMBUS device is explained by the following Microsoft article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2925727/unknown-device-vmbus-in-device-manager-in-virtual-machine-for-avma